# Do Poe AI, Open AI, and Claude AI generate all answers from training data, including factual and logical answers or from personal information?

Tags: open-ai, question-answering

Do Poe AI, Open AI, and Claude AI generate all answers from training data, including factual and logical answers or from firsthand personal information?